# С# Не могу понять почему мерцают отрисованные объекты

Tags: c#, winforms

При запуске игры все объекты отображаются, но при этом заметно мерцание, не могу понять как от этого избавится, пробовал двойную буфферизаю, не помогло. Прошу отнестись понимающе и помочь. Спасибо.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SnakeGame
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Point[] p;
        Point apple;
        int len; // Длина змейки
        int direction; // 1 - влево, 2 - вправо, 3 - вверх, 4 - вниз
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            p = new Point[200];
            len = 5;
            direction = 3;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                p[i].X = 100;
                p[i].Y = 100+i*10;
            }
            apple.X = 10;
            apple.Y = 10;
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Invalidate();
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 198; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                p[i + 1].X = p[i].X;
                p[i + 1].Y = p[i].Y;
            }
            if (direction == 1)
            {
                p[0].X = p[1].X - 10;
                p[0].Y = p[1].Y;
            }
            if (direction == 2)
            {
                p[0].X = p[1].X + 10;
                p[0].Y = p[1].Y;
            }
            if (direction == 3)
            {
                p[0].X = p[1].X;
                p[0].Y = p[1].Y - 10;
            }
            if (direction == 4)
            {
                p[0].X = p[1].X;
                p[0].Y = p[1].Y + 10;
            }
            SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.OrangeRed);
            for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(b, p[i].X, p[i].Y, 15, 15);
            }
            SolidBrush b1 = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkGreen);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(b1, apple.X, apple.Y, 15, 15);
            }
            if(p[0].X == apple.X && p[0].Y == apple.Y)
            {
                len++;
                Random R;
                R = new Random();
                apple.X = R.Next(0, 50) * 10;
                apple.Y = R.Next(0, 50) * 10;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
                direction = 1;
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
                direction = 2;
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
                direction = 3;
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
                direction = 4;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: потому, что используется винформс... Он в принципе мигает) думаю что нужно смотреть в сторону буферизации. То есть сначала отрисовать рисунок в памяти в буфер, а потом менять его на самой форме.... Попробуй погуглить в сторону "flickering C# winforms", думаю, там ты найдешь более толковый ответ.

Comment: @Andrew Спасибо за ответ, действительно дело в буфферизации, просто на просторах интернета много неправильных примеров активизации этого самого буфера, поэтому нашел хороший пример на просторах ютюба

Comment: запости ответ в єтот вопрос на тему способа буферизации, который ты нашел. Для будущих поколений)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы найдено!

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams handleparam = base.CreateParams;
        handleparam.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;
        return handleparam;
    }
}
```